# Can you create a joined view from task list and related content?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a view of approval tasks that also includes a column from the related form library.  I have tried creating a linked data source between the tasks list and the form library, but have trouble finding much information on creating linked views with the task list.

I have tried: 
http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/joining-the-task-list-with-related-content-in-a-dvwp/
without luck - it just tells me "there are no items to show in this view." which I assume means it couldn't be joined correctly with the specified table.

I am using the standard approval workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest solution I've found so far

```
1.) Create task form fields in SharePoint designer.

2.) Go into Approval(1) to add the task form fields.

3.) Click 'Change the behavior of a single task'. Add 'Set task field' action in the Before a task is assigned section to set the task form fields to get the value of Current Item:ID.

4.) Use the new task field to create your subview on your linked datasource
```

While not optimal - and it created me many different problems - I was able to create the view desired.
Hopefully someone will come up with a better solution.